# How to add a new JPanel instance every time I click on JButton in JFrame in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working with the [Eclipse IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). I have added Panel from a different class extending `JPanel` to a `JFrame` of a different class.

I have added a 'New' `JButton` on Frame. I added `<JPanel instance>.setVisible(true)` on actionListener event of that button. But when I press the 'New' button it shows the previous instance of `JPanel`. I want to add a new instance of that panel when I press a 'New' `JButton`.

Here is the code for my button:

```
final Rec r = new Rec();
JButton btnNew = new JButton("New Receipt");
btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        r.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(r,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
});
```

Here, Rec is a class extending JPanel.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: "_I have added panel from a differnt class extending JPanel to a JFrame of different class_" you should have a good reason to do this.

Comment: Also can you tell us what  `Rec r = new Rec() ` contains?What you want to do exactly?

Comment: yes i am working on a billing software,which works fullscreen.i want to add a panel which has a full structure of Receipt format.so whenever i click on 'New Receipt' button it should create a new instance of Rec panel so i can work on receipt.

Comment: It has a vertical box layout,which contains some labels,textfields and buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use a `LayoutManager` on your frame that supports multiple panels.  I suggest look into `FlowLayout` for now - it's the simplest to learn if you're starting out fresh with Swing.  You also need to call `frame.add(panel)` to display the panel.  You shouldn't need to call `setVisible(true)` as all `JPanel` instances come visible by default.

You also need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on your `JFrame` whenever you add or remove a panel - this forces the layout to update itself with any changes that were made in the `JFrame`'s underlying `Component` list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your full code, so did a short exmaple here to clear up things.

- As stated in above answer, you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`
- Change/modify as per your `LayoutManager`

  ```
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

  /**
   * @author rohan
   */
  public class TestPanel {

      private JFrame frame;
      private JPanel panel;
      private JTextArea jTextArea;
      private JButton butt;

      TestPanel() {
          createGUI();
          process1();
      }

      private void process1() {
          jTextArea.setText("hii");
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      private void createGUI() {
          butt = new JButton("button");
          frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          panel = new JPanel();
          jTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);
          panel.add(jTextArea);
          panel.add(butt);
          butt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                  final JPanel pan = new JPanel();
                  JButton but = new JButton("CHANGED");
                  pan.add(but);
                  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          frame.add(pan);
                          butt.setVisible(false);
                          jTextArea.setVisible(false);
                          pan.revalidate();
                          pan.repaint();
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
          frame.add(panel);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(false);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  new TestPanel();
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```